# Select multiple rows from pandas data frame where one of column contains some values as NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Select rows with columns ['A','B'] where rows with column 'C' contain NaN values in python (Pandas)

1. I have pandas data frame with three columns 'A' , 'B', 'C'.
2. In column 'C' there are some rows which contains NaN values.

Now I want to select column 'A' and column 'B' of data frame where column 'C' contains NaN values.

If all columns or only one column needs to be selected then I can do below,

```
df['A'][df['C'].isnull()]
```

or

```
df[df['C'].isnull()]
```

but I am not getting how to select multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put multiple column names in the first form.

```
df[['A','B']][df['C'].isnull()]
```

Comment: It is better add .copy() at the end

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loc`, and select a list of columns:

```
df.loc[df['C'].isnull(), ['A','B']]
```

For example

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6,7,8], 'C':[np.nan,1,np.nan,2]})     

>>> df                                                                                                   
   A  B    C                                                                                             
0  1  5  NaN
1  2  6  1.0
2  3  7  NaN
3  4  8  2.0

>>> df.loc[df['C'].isnull(), ['A','B']]                                                                     
   A  B                                                                                                  
0  1  5
2  3  7
```

Comment: It is better add .copy() at the end

Answer (score 1):

I like `dropna` and `drop` , since we will not have copy warning when we forget add the `.copy()`

```
sub=df.dropna(subset=['C']).drop('C',1)
sub
Out[26]: 
   A  B
1  2  6
3  4  8
```

Comment: Its not generic solution as we may have more number of columns in a data frame but we want to show only few in result.

Comment: @Gopu_TunasG df.dropna(subset=['C'])[['A','B']].copy()